# Laravel 5.2 language support (Hebrew)

Tags: php, laravel, hebrew, laravel-blade

When I try to write in Hebrew in my layout file, it shows as question marks after extending it in the index page, but when I try to write in Hebrew in the index page itself, the Hebrew would show up fine. What's wrong with the @extends function?

Comment: Make sure your layout file is encoded correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: My layout is encoded in utf 8.... And the lang is set to heb. It works in a normal plain php file without the framework but not with laravel.